# Reading response from http adapter procedure

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a response from a web server:

```
  { 
  "errors": [ ],
  "info": [ ], 
  "isSuccessful": true, 
  "responseHeaders": 
  {
  "Connection": "close",
  "Content-Length": "159",
  "Content-Type": "text\/html",
  "Date": "Sat, 20 Feb 2016 11:15:35 GMT", 
  "Server": "Apache",
  "X-Powered-By": "PHP\/5.2.17" }, 
  "responseTime": 705,
  "statusCode": 200, 
  "statusReason": "OK", 
  "text": "True \n<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/stats.hosting24.com\/count.php\"><\/script>\n<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->", 
  "totalTime": 706, 
  "warnings": [ ]
  }
```

My snippet to retrieve the true value:

```
 var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

    // Extract value from the response.
    var type = typeof response; 
    if ("object" == type) {
        if (true == response["isSuccessful"]) {

            // Drill down into the response object.
            var results = response["results"];
            var result = results[0];


            var val = result["text"];

            // Return JSON object
            return val;
        } 
        else {
            // Returning null. Web request was not successful.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How to drill down and extract only the value from the `"text": "True"` in the **adapter-impl.js**??

Can I have some please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this way.one more thing,look you want to  return `json object`.so, must be write json format or convert json.

```
 var response= WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

    if (response.statusCode==200 && response.isSuccessful==true){

        var val =response.text

            return {

                data:val

            }


    }
    else{

        return null
    }
```

Comment: come on , you return json format ,so you have to make sure key value pair ."data" is key .on the other hand, your The "val" is plaintext.  check this link please  http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp